# On rational Ramanujan-type series for $1/\pi$

Tags: modular-forms, sequences-and-series, ramanujan

A Ramanujan-type series for $1/\pi$ is a series of the following form
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n(\frac{1}{s})_n(1-\frac{1}{s})_n}{(1)_n^3} (bn+a) z^n=\frac{1}{\pi},
$$
where $(c)_n=c(c+1)\cdots (c+n-1)$ (the rising factorial), $s=2, \, 3, \, 4$ or $6$, and $z, \, b$ and $a$ are algebraic numbers. When $z$ and $a/b$ are rational, we can write the series as an infinite sum of rational numbers
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_n(\frac{1}{s})_n(1-\frac{1}{s})_n}{(1)_n^3} (n+a/b) z^n=\frac{1}{b \pi},
$$
and then it is said that is a rational Ramanujan-type series for $1/\pi$. We know that the values of $z$ and $a/b$ are obtained by using the properties of modular forms. As I have never seen a Ramanujan-type series for $1/\pi$ with a rational value of $z$ and $a/b$ being algebraic but not rational, I have the following question:

QUESTION: Does $z$ rational implies that $a/b$ is rational as well? If the answer is "yes", could you give an argument?. If the answer is "no", could you show an example of a Ramanujan-type series with $z$ rational and $a/b$ algebraic but not rational?

Comment: Nice observation! I also haven't seen counterexamples. But if this was proven true, it would be quite powerful for computing a/b!

Comment: My guess is that all the series with these rational parameters were already found by Ramanujan (except the one by Chudnovsky). It's highly unlikely that we have more series with rational $z$.

Comment: Ramanujan wrote 16 rational series for 1/pi, but there are 36 rational convergent Ramanujan-type series, and also rational series of Ramanujan-Sato-type. (see the tables in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232016510_Rational_analogues_of_Ramanujan's_series_for_1I, and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.07394.pdf).

Comment: Milla, I am reading Chapter 10 of your paper on the Chudnovsky's series, and I find it really interesting!

Comment: Thank you! And this is another nice paper with many such series: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07350

Comment: Glad to read your paper (including tables which list rational series).